# How do I view the compiled machine code or byte code for a C++ function in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, .net-assembly

What is the best (quickest) way to view the code that the compiler generated from my files? I'm using mostly C++ but a solution that works for .NET languages would be very welcome as well.

Comment: set a breakpoint, press CTRL+F11

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Within Visual Studio, go to the property pages for your project, then go to `C/C++ → Output Files →  Assembler Output`. It should look something like this:

[image: property page]

Note the corresponding compiler switches, all variants of [`/FA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx).

- `/FA`: Assembly-Only Listing
- `/FAcs`: Assembly, Machine Code and Source
- `/FAc`: Assembly With Machine Code
- `/FAs`: Assembly With Source Code

Underneath the "Assembler Output" option there's an "ASM List Location" option. This is equivalent to the `/Fa` switch (note capitalization!), and it sets the file path of the output listing.

You can also look at the assembly while debugging (at a breakpoint), complete with the corresponding source code, by right-clicking the current line in the source file text area and clicking "Go To Disassembly".

[image: gotodisassembly]

It'll jump to the assembly at the line you right-clicked on in a separate tab. The listing will resemble this:

[image]

<sub>Yes I know, the screenshots are not from Visual Studio 2010 but the steps and the general appearance are the same. I just don't have immediate access to VS2010 to make screenshots with. :-)</sub>

Comment: This answer is _awesome_.  However, I believe when you have it do the assembler output, I believe it doesn't create binaries.  If I recall that correctly, you should note it somewhere.

Comment: @MooingDuck: this is true for a separate preprocessor run (/P), but at least in VC2010, the /FA variants do still generate binaries.

Answer (score 7):

For a C++ project, compile with [`/FA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx) to get an assembly listing.

For .NET assemblies, there's [`ildasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For .NET you can use the `ildasm` tool which comes with the framework to view the IL.